# (Android) Resizing images with a transparent background?

Tags: java, android, image, background, resize

I'm getting images through an API, except the problem is that all the images are in a fixed size, which leaves large pictures okay since it takes up the whole space, but there are some pictures with small objects, as shown here

[image_large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhdOS.png)

I was wondering if there is a way to detect if an image with a transparent background can be resized to only what's shown such as here

[image_small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1hFw.png)

The libraries I'm using for this are glide to get the images from a URL and GifImageView to hold the image. Any help would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I think that scalingtype attribute will be helpful.
And with glide, there is a method called apply() that you can use it to determine the option that you can use to modify you imageView

RequestOptions cropOptions = new RequestOptions().centerCrop(context);
...
Glide.with(fragment)
.load(url)
.apply(cropOptions)
.into(imageView);
You can benefit from the documentations of glide library

https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/options.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that. The problem is that Glide recognizes the empty transparent background as part of the image, so scaling it to will make the image so small that I cannot see anything (as can be seen here https://i.imgur.com/474CTqH.png)

Comment: I think that the problem is in the image itself, I faced a similar issue when I tried to set a big image as an icon. you need to refactor the image or edited "viewportWidth" and "viewportHeight"

Comment: Yes, I have stated that the issue is the image. There's a small object in a big frame. The viewportWidth/Height solution wouldn't work well for me because not everything I request from the API is going to be a small object in a large frame. Unless I can find out how to do this dynamically?